# Non-latin text outputting as nonsense in Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I've got a script which makes a JSON request that may return text in any script, then outputs the text (I dont have any control over the text being returned).

It works fine with latin characters, but other scripts output as a mojibake, and I'm not sure what's going wrong.

In the response, the problematic characters are encoded using \u syntax.  In particular, I have a string containing `\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bf\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b5` which should output as `испытание` but instead outputs as `Ð¸ÑÐ¿ÑÑÐ°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ`.

Obviously this is something to do with how python deals with unicode and UTF, but I despite all I've read I don't understand what's going on well enough to know how to solve it.

I've tried to extract the salient points from the code below:

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params, cookies=self.cookies, auth=self.auth)
text = response.text
print text
status = json.loads(text)
print status
for folder in status['folders']
  print folder['name']
```

Output:

```
{ "folders": [ { "name": "\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bf\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b5" } ] }

{u'folders': [{ u'name': u'\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd1\x8b\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5' }]}

Ð¸ÑÐ¿ÑÑÐ°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ
```

I've also tried

```
status = response.json();
for folder in status['folders']:
    print folder['name']
```

With the same result.

Note, I'm really passing the string to a GTKMenuItem to be displayed, but the output from `print`ing the string is the same as from showing it in the menu.

Comment: Mmh... Actually that should be `\u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435`. The actual UTF-8 encoding is `\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd1\x8b\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5`. Anyway, can you show a piece of code?

Comment: Thanks, I've added an example of the code above. It looks like it is being encoded along the way as you say, but the output is mangled.

Comment: It looks like whatever site you're requesting this JSON from is broken, to me.

Comment: @Wooble, can you elaborate?

Comment: use `status = response.json()` to detect the character encoding of the json text correctly. It is not necessary in your case (the response is in ascii range) but it can help for non-ascii input.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That didn't help I'm afraid, although it is a better way of doing it than my current method, thanks!

Comment: @marxjohnson @J.F.Sebastian's answer will help you on the client side, but if you have access to the server, it should be fixed, because it's encoding things wrong. Note that JSON's **default** encoding is UTF-8, so sending the string as-is (without `\uXXXX` encoding) would be just as good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ricardo Cárdenes said in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954694/non-latin-text-outputting-as-nonsense-in-python?noredirect=1#comment33262540_21954694) the server sends incorrect response. The response that you've got is double encoded:

```
>>>> u = u'\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd1\x8b\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5'
>>>> print u.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
испытание
```

The correct string would look like:

```
>>>> s = {u"name": u"испытание"}
>>>> import json
>>>> print json.dumps(s)
{"name": "\u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435"}

>>>> print s['name']
испытание
>>>> print s['name'].encode('unicode-escape')
\u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435
>>>> print s['name'].encode('utf-8')
испытание
>>>> s['name'].encode('utf-8')
'\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd1\x8b\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5'
```

Comment: Fixing the server would be even better, but this will get him the right string, at least.

Comment: Unfortunately as I said in the question, I've got no scope for changing what the server sends.  In case you're interested, it's a BitTorrent Sync server, which is proprietary.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for your answer. It helped me a ton, @jfs